# Subclassing UITableViewController what you get?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

This is probably me being a little dim, I am setting up a UITableViewController via a UINavigationController, I have subclassed UITableViewController: (see below) and have implemented the datasource methods to get my table up and running

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSArray *dataList;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSArray *dataList;
@end
```

My question is: when I came to implement the viewDidLoad for RootViewController I wanted to set the title for the table (See image below). I looked at the docs for UITableViewController and found that it had a property called "tableView" so I tried ...

```
[[self tableView] setTitle:@"Eeek!"];
```

This did not work, what I should have tried was ...

```
[self setTitle:@"Eeek!"];
```

What I am wondering, when you subclass UITableViewController and add code your actually dealing with the tableView and not the UITableViewController, does this make sense?

[image]

Gary

Comment: What exactly do you mean by setting the title of the table? The title that rests just above the table cells, or the title on the navigation bar?

Comment: The title on the blue bar that sits between the iphones Status Bar and the cells (see above image), the title is "Eeek!"

Comment: I get it, the title property is actually on the UIViewController which is inherited by UITableViewController. I was getting confused when I could not see "title" as a property of UITableViewController, I fully understand now, it is there, you just need to follow the beard crumbs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are setting is actually the UIViewController (the parent class of UITableViewController) title, which is what UINavigationController uses to display a title in its navigationBar (the blue bar in your image)

Edit to better answer question: so no, when you subclass UITableViewController, you are actually dealing with the controller, not the table view itself.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer to the question, no - you are still dealing with the properties of the Controller.  The difference between the two `setTitle:` operations is:

```
// This message is being sent to the UITableViewController
[self setTitle:@"Eeek!"];

// This message is being sent to the UITableView property of the UITableViewController
[[self tableView] setTitle:@"Eeek!"];
```

There is no `setTitle:` method on the `UITableView` object, so that fails.

Abstractly in terms of MVC, the first is setting the property on a Controller and the second is setting the property on a View.